# How to set x264 encode parameters through ffmpeg AVCodecContext

Tags: ffmpeg, libx264

I'm trying to use **ffmpeg/libx264** to encode and transmit a real-time video, when I use `av_dict_set(&opts, "tune", "zerolatency", 0);`  the system works well. As the X264 encode parameters are set by *ffmpeg* using `av_dict_set`, for some research purpose I want to change them by myself. But some parameters in  `x264_param_t` can not correspond to those parameters in  `AVCodecContext`, such as `vfr_input`. So I want to know if there is a directly way to transmit parameters into X264 encoder when using **libx264** in *ffmpeg*.

---

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try calling `av_opt_set` with the codec context `priv_data` structure:

```
AVCodec *codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
AVCodecContext *codecContex = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
av_opt_set(codecContex->priv_data, "preset", "ultrafast", 0);
av_opt_set(codecContex->priv_data, "tune", "zerolatency", 0);
```

Error checking omitted for brevity.

Comment: Using these options, though my decoding lags heavily. Neglecting 150 ms for encoding a frame and 150 ms for decoding,it almost takes 6 to 7 seconds later to see the current frame at decoded output,, where this sync issue may come from?? Also, got_output is set after `12 calls` to `avcodec_encode_video2` Any workaround?

Comment: @nmxprime How did you configure AVCodecContext? Try to use a minimal configuration based on the [encoding_decoding.c](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/decoding__encoding_8c-source.html) example.

Comment: Yeah i got it! As those presets are overridden by user setting, i got delay, because of the CBR setting i configured! I want to set `vbv-buffersize`. tried `av_opt_set_int`, but not working, returned -ve value.