# C++ ffmpeg x264 encoding settings

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, x264

I want to set the x264 encoding settings via FFMPEG C++ SDK,
how can I set it?

Now, I use the `av_opt_set` function but it seems not work. 
(ex. `av_opt_set(c->priv_data, "cabac", "0", 0);`)

I want to set the settings in below.

```
cabac=1 ref=1 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 G...fast_pskip=1  chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=1 keyint_minG...=1 scenecut=40  intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
```

Does anybody know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You're making the exact same mistake as this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22211230/translating-ffmpeg-command-line-to-c-codec-settings). And my answer is the same here as it was there:

Don't pass `c->priv_data` to `av_opt_set`. Pass the context. As in:

```
av_opt_set(c, "cabac", "0", 0);
```

Internally, `av_opt_set` [will cast the object to an `AVClass*`](http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/opt_8c_source.html#l01496) which is [what holds all the options](http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVClass.html#a8f5d64df6aeeecce08ab33d0afb07f92).

But you don't have to worry about any of that. You just need to call `av_opt_set` with the context, and it will handle all the dirty details for you. Again, just to be clear, you should just be calling `av_opt_set(c, "cabac", "0", 0);`.

Comment: oh, you saved my day!! BTW, why the example code pass the `c->priv_data` rather than context?

Comment: @Andy: Good, glad to help! Which example code?

Comment: I reference this [document](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/decoding_encoding_8c-example.html) from FFmpeg.

Comment: @Andy: hmmm... let me ask about it on the mailing list and get back to here.

Comment: Thank you , looking forward to the answer to this question.