# In ffmpeg command-line, how to show all filter settings and their parameters before encoding?

Tags: ffmpeg

Is there a way to force the `ffmpeg` command-line to display a comprehensive list of all filters and their parameters, even those that are applied automatically like `-vf scale`?

(*EDIT:* To clarify, I do not mean filter documentation, but rather displaying filters that are instantiated at runtime for a particular command-line, just before transcoding starts. The goal of this is mostly checking that ffmpeg is indeed doing the right thing and not inserting/changing filters when I do not intend it to.)

There are a few options available, but none are comprehensive enough. For example:

- The `lavfi` module has a `dumpgraph` option ([here](http://underpop.online.fr/f/ffmpeg/help/lavfi.htm.gz)) but only if you're using `lavfi`.
- The `-sws_flags print_info` option ([here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-scaler.html)) can be used to determine if `-vf scale` is applied automatically and shows a subset of its parameters, but not all of them.

Additionally, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22211230/translating-ffmpeg-command-line-to-c-codec-settings) appears related the answer doesn't answer what I'm looking for.

Are there better ways to achieve that?

Answer (score 4):

`ffmpeg -filters` is what you're looking for

it shows an entire list of the the available filters and how they can be used with the input/output

The only thing it is missing is the parameters. But you can find those on their online docs https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html

***EDIT:***  **To print filter parameters and more on the command line:**

Use `ffmpeg --help filter=filter_name`, replacing `filter_name` with your filter of interest.

This works also for: `decoder`s, `encoder`s, `demuxer`s, `muxer`s, `filter`s, bitstream filters (`bsf`) & `protocol`s.

```
-h type=name -- print all options for the named decoder/encoder/demuxer/muxer/filter/bsf/protocol
See man ffmpeg for detailed description of the options.
```

For example:

```
ffmpeg --help encoder=mpeg2video # For help on mpeg2video codec options
```

Comment: Ah, this makes me realize my question was poorly worded : I meant "all filters applied at runtime". I know how to get to the docs, but getting to know the exact list of filters and their parameters applied on a particular command-line was what I was looking for! Editing the question!

Comment: Naw your wording makes complete sense. The first part of my comment answers that - `ffmpeg -filters` will show all the filters available with your ffmpeg executable.

The docs I just added for more info for any others stumbling across this :)

Comment: Hmm, it seems it's still not _quite_ what I was looking for. In fact I can see 3 different things: there's a) a list of all filters technically supported by ffmpeg, b) a list of all filters compiled into a particular ffmpeg executable, and c) a list of all filters (with their parameters and the values associated with each parameter) applied by a particular command-line. I can get a) with the docs and b) with your answer, but I was looking for c)... Sorry again for the poor wording, and thanks for trying to help!